# Как распредилить стили на React?

Tags: reactjs

В общем вопрос такой: 
У меня есть 2 страницы: Main.js и Login.js и у каждого есть стиль Main.css и Login.css. Проблема в том что когда зайду на Main загружается стили и Main.css и Login.css. Как их распредилить чтобы по отдельности загружался?

Comment: Проверьте import-ы в начале файлов. Возможно вы там подключили оба файла стилей

Comment: мне понравилась реализация написания стилей у react material ui, можете попробовать)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У ваших страничек нету никаких отдельных стилей, все собирается в один CSS файл и что бы небыло никаких конфликтов, нужно давать разные имена классам или правильно комбинировать селекторы. Если вам лень, или вы не умеете это делать, или вы просто хотите облегчить себе работу(тут сомнительно), можно использовать CSS модули или модные нонче библиотеки CSS-IN-JS для изоляции стилей, но опять же, это не какая-то магия, а банальная работа с селекторами и именами классов на стадии сборки.